# Building a GUI for a warehouse where I display items read throught TCP but the window stays loading

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, sockets, pyqt5

First of all I am not a programer, so I might be messing up with the classes. The purpose of my code is to parse the ecp code of what i am reading and displying it in a table though a GUI. But the window stays loading. The data read through tcp should be read constantly since it can be sent anytime. Could you please review my code and where am I messing up? Thanks in advance.

```
import socket
import json
import sys
import pandas as pd
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer, QObject, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot

df = pd.read_csv('almacen.csv', sep = ';', on_bad_lines='skip')
TCP_IP = "192.168.50.129"
TCP_PORT = 14150
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

#data= '{"antennaPort":1,"epc":"000100000058602001000767","firstSeenTimestamp":1683294299497785,"peakRssi":-55,"isHeartBeat":false}{"antennaPort":1,"epc":"000100000058602001001257","firstSeenTimestamp":1683294299497785,"peakRssi":-55,"isHeartBeat":false}'
l1,l2,l3 = [],[],[]

class TcpClient(QObject):
    data_received = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, host, port):
        super().__init__()
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.socket = None

    def connect(self):
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        try:
            self.socket.connect((self.host, self.port))
            print("conectado a socket")
            self.receive_data()
        except ConnectionRefusedError:
            print("Connection refused.")

    def receive_data(self):
        while True:
            data = self.socket.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode("utf-8")
            if data:
                self.data_received.emit(data)

    def close(self):
        self.socket.close()

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Lectura de salidas de almacén")
        self.setFixedSize(1360, 768)
        #self.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")

        # Background image
        background_label = QLabel(self)
        pixmap = QPixmap("background.png")  # Replace "background_image.jpg" with your actual image path
        background_label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        background_label.setGeometry(0, 0, 1360, 768)
        background_label.setScaledContents(True)

        # Logo images
        logo_left = QLabel(self)
        pixmap_left = QPixmap("logo_left.png")  # Replace "logo_left.png" with your actual image path
        logo_left.setPixmap(pixmap_left)
        logo_left.setGeometry(50, 50, pixmap_left.width(), pixmap_left.height())
        logo_left.setScaledContents(True)

        logo_right = QLabel(self)
        pixmap_right = QPixmap("logo_right.png")  # Replace "logo_right.png" with your actual image path
        logo_right.setPixmap(pixmap_right)
        logo_right.setGeometry(1360 - pixmap_right.width() - 50, 50, pixmap_right.width(), pixmap_right.height())
        logo_right.setScaledContents(True)

        # Data table
        self.title_label = QLabel("<u>Repuestos leidos...</u>", self)
        #title_label.setStyleSheet("color : red")
        self.title_label.setGeometry(530, 160, 300, 50)
        font = QFont("Arial", 18, QFont.Bold)
        self.title_label.setFont(font)

        self.table_widget = QTableWidget(self)
        self.table_widget.setGeometry(200, 230, 960, 400)

        # Set table font
        font = QFont("Arial", 12)
        self.table_widget.setFont(font)

        # Set table properties
        self.table_widget.setEditTriggers(QTableWidget.NoEditTriggers)
        self.table_widget.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
        self.table_widget.setSelectionMode(QTableWidget.NoSelection)

        # Insert initial data into table
        self.generate_data()

        # Adjust table frame to table size
        #table_widget.resizeColumnsToContents()
        #table_widget.resizeRowsToContents()

        # Buttons
        # button1 = QPushButton("Limpiar", self)
        # button1.setGeometry(1140, 670, 150, 50)

        button2 = QPushButton("LIMPIAR", self)
        button2.setFont(QFont('Arial', 12))
        button2.setGeometry(1000, 670, 150, 50)
        button2.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)
        
        self.counter = 30
        self.label = QLabel("Reiniciando la lista automáticamente en... "+str(self.counter), self)
        self.label.setGeometry(600, 670, 400, 50)
        self.label.setFont(QFont('Arial', 12))
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_counter)
        self.timer.start(1000)  # 1 second

        self.tcp_client = TcpClient(TCP_IP, TCP_PORT)
        self.tcp_client.data_received.connect(self.handle_data)

    def button_clicked(self):
        self.reset_counter()
        self.update_table()

    def update_table(self):
        self.table_widget.clear()

        # Insert data into table
        self.table_widget.setColumnCount(len(self.df2.columns))
        self.table_widget.setRowCount(len(self.df2.index))
        self.table_widget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self.df2.columns)

        for i, row in enumerate(self.df2.values):
            for j, value in enumerate(row):
                item = QTableWidgetItem(str(value))
                self.table_widget.setItem(i, j, item)


    def generate_data(self):
        datos ={'Código de Artículo': l1, 'Nombre de Artículo': l2, 'Cantidad': l3}
        self.df2 = pd.DataFrame(datos)
        self.update_table()

    def update_counter(self):
        self.counter -= 1
        self.label.setText("Reiniciando la lista automáticamente en... "+str(self.counter))
        self.label.setFont(QFont('Arial', 12))
        if self.counter == 0:
            self.timer.stop()
            self.label.setText("Limpiando...")
            self.reset_counter()


    def reset_counter(self):
        global l1, l2, l3
        l1,l2,l3 = [],[],[]
        self.counter = 30
        self.timer.start()


    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def handle_data(self, data):
        json_objects = data.split('}{')
        for json_str in json_objects:
            if not json_str.startswith('{'):
                json_str = '{' + json_str
            if not json_str.endswith('}'):
                json_str = json_str + '}'
            pdata = json.loads(json_str)
            epc_value = pdata['epc']
            c = str(epc_value[12:18] + "-" + epc_value[18:24])
            l1.append(c)
            lf= list(set(l1))
            lista = df.index[df['codigo_articulo'] == c].tolist()
            listaf= list(set(lista))
            cell_val = df.iloc[lista[0]]["nombre_articulo"]
            l2.append(cell_val)
        for j in lf:
            count = l1.count(j)
            l3.append(count)
        self.datos ={'Código de Artículo': lf, 'Nombre de Artículo': l2, 'Cantidad': l3}
        self.df2 = pd.DataFrame(self.datos)
        self.update_table()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        try:
            self.tcp_client.close()
        except s.error as e:
            print("Error closing socket:", str(e))
        event.accept()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    window.tcp_client.connect()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What do you mean by _the window stays loading_? Do you see `conectado a socket` or what?

Comment: Yes I see "conectado a socket" but the window is displayed blank and with the windows loading circle.

Comment: That `while True` in `receive_data` is blocking, and since it's called from the main thread, it completely prevents the main event loop to process events, including showing the UI. Use QThread.